# ANDROID app something weird

Tags: android, constructor

I just encountered something weird. I'm developing an ANDROID app on ANDROID Studio and running the test version on my ANDROID smartphone. Within the JAVA code of of the main activity I do the following:

```
public static ArrayList arrayListAvailableOptions = new ArrayList();
```

Later in the app I add three items to arrayListAvailableOptions and I display the number of items in the arrayListAvailableOptions using the array's size() method. I start the app running via the Run option on ANDROID studio and it works fine. It shows that the array list does indeed contain three items.

I then exit the app using the back button on the smartphone.

And THEN I start the app up again, this time by clicking on the app icon on the smartphone itself (NOT via the Run button in ANDROID Studio).

But now it shows that there are SIX items in arrayListAvailableOptions. Each time that I exit the app and start it up again, there are three more items in arrayListAvailableOptions . FIrst 3, then 6, then 9, etc.

It's as if the smartphone is keeping the app in memory and each time I start it up and it encounters the

```
public static ArrayList arrayListAvailableOptions = new ArrayList();
```

it checks to see if arrayListAvailableOptions already exists, and if it does, doesn't bother actually DOING that operation, i.e. calling the constructor.

I found that if I explicitly clear() the arrayListAvailableOptions, as with:

```
    public static ArrayList arrayListAvailableOptions = new ArrayList();
   arrayListAvailableOptions.clear();
```

then it works as expected, with an empty arrayListAvailableOptions each time I start up the app.

But this behavior is disturbing. It really shouldn't require an explicit clear() in order to assure that there's nothing left over from a prior running of the app.

Comment: I can confirm that behavior for my apps tested on Android version 2.2. Android activities are finished using the back button, but usually the app process that hosts activities is still alive and with it all static objects (such as your `ArrayList`). An `Activity` is just another object living in an app process and its destruction does not necessarily mean that the process is finished with it. A similar problem are background threads that can keep on running when the activity that created it is already finished.

Comment: To be clear, "exiting" the app using the back button does not guarantee your app or associated static variables are destroyed.